# Почему функция не возвращает переменную?

Tags: swift

При нажатии на кнопку login:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let userEmail = emailOrUsernameField.text;
    let userPassword = passwordField.text;

    if(userEmail!.isEmpty || userPassword!.isEmpty){

    }else
    {

        let json: [String: String] = ["username": userEmail!, "password": userPassword!]
        print(login(json: json))//ничего не выводит
        if(login(json: json).isEmpty){
            print("error")//даже ошибку не выводит
        }
        else{
             self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "protectedAfterLogin", sender: self)//об этом и речи быть не может

        }

    }
}
```

Функция POST запроса:

```
func login(json:Any)->String{
    var token:String = "";
    guard let url = URL(string: ngrok+"/api/auth/token/create")else{return "3"}
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")

    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])else {return "2"}
    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request){(data, response, error) in
        if let response = response{
            print(response)
        }
        guard let data = data else{return}
        do{
            print(data)
            if let json_response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])as? [String:Any]{

                if let temp_token = json_response["auth_token"]{
                    print(temp_token as! String)//выводит нормальный результат
                    token = temp_token as! String;//должен заполнить token
                }
            }
        }

        catch{
            print(error)
        }
        }.resume()
    return token;
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку формируется json словарь и передается в функцию отправки запроса, которая должна вернуть токен. Токен она пишет(принт в login), а возвращает даже не пустую строку, так как error не выводится. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что `session.dataTask` начинает выполнение запроса к серверу в отдельном потоке. Функция-же в этом коде возвращает `token` сразу-же, не успевая дождаться ответа от сервера.

Рекомендую добавить `callback`, который будет вызван при получении ответа:

```swift
func login(json: Any, callback: @escaping (_ token: String?) -> ()) {
```

И дальше, при получении ответа, вызывать этот `callback`

```swift
...
                if let temp_token = json_response["auth_token"]{
                    print(temp_token as! String)//выводит нормальный результат
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {   // Перевод в главный поток, чтобы безопасно работать с UI
 /* вот тут -> */       callback(temp_token as! String) //должен заполнить token
                    }
...
```

При этом придется немного поменять вызов функции `login`:

```swift
...
login(json: json) { [weak self] token in
    guard let self = self 
        else { return }
    guard let token = token, !token.isEmpty
        else {
        print("error")//даже ошибку не выводит
        return
    }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "protectedAfterLogin", sender: self)//об этом и речи быть не может
}
...
```

Comment: Спасибо. Токен получаю, но когда доходит до perfomSegue получаю _terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException_ и _Thread 3: signal SIGABRT_. withIdentifier укзан верно.

Comment: еще вопрос: Где можно почитать про [эту](https://pastebin.com/pj5wg1Bm) часть кода? Вообще не понимаю, что там. И если я хочу отлавливать разные ошибки при запросе(неверные данные для авторизации, timeout error, страница не найдена и так далее) мне необходимо добавить еще один выходной параметр - error code, и после выполнения функции, в зависимости от error code показывать пользователю тот или иной текст.  А сам error code заполнять в func login. Нормальное решение?

Comment: Еще можно как то ограничить выполнение функции login, чтобы если ответ от сервера идет долго, пользователь не смог спамить сервер новыми запросами?

Comment: @hohfiofi Про `guard` можно почитать тут: [Официальная документация](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html) в разделе `Early Exit`. В кратце, это как `if`, только наоборот. Решение добавить дополнительный параметр выглядит неплохо. Можно сделать чуть красивее, используя новый тип [`Result`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0235-add-result.md) из Swift 5. Обычно, пользователя ограничивают, показывая на экране какую-нибудь крутилку. Это дает понять, что происходит важный процесс авторизации.

Comment: Про `signal SIGABRT`. Надо добавить переход в главный поток (`DispatchQueue.main.async`) перед использованием segue, видимо data task  возвращает ответ в другом потоке. Исправлю код в ответе.

Comment: Пишу теперь проверку с [этой же](https://pastebin.com/cqJc0XzN) функцией в AppDelegate. И получаю очень странную ошибку. Хотя это не совсем ошибка , редактор не ругается, да и сервер 200 отвечает. Дело в том, что код ниже (if(!tempToken.isEmpty))  выполняется раньше кода выше(if(!username.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty)). Опять, что-то с потоками не так?

Comment: И можно как-то сделать функцию с POST запросом синхронной? А то никак не могу отловить ошибку, когда сервер выключен. Доходит до    URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: request){(data, response, error) , а потом сразу на resume()

Comment: Рекомендую создать отдельны вопрос про синхронные POST функии, он будет виден большему числу людей, а значит больше шанс получить хороший ответ ;)